# Can't unblock maven mirror block (I need to update the methods)

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I found my self with the "blocked mirror" error when building the maven project.
I'm trying some ways to correct this error:

1. I replaced the version of maven.
2. I checked the file (local-settings.xml) and I not found the row with the blocking:

   ```xml
   <mirror>
         <id>mirrorId</id>
         <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
         <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
         <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
   </mirror>
   ```

My project still doesn't run.

If I replace the repository in my file (in the pom.xml) to repository from the mvnrepository.com, I need to update the method "swipe"...but I don't know how?

This is what appears in my file:

```
@Step ("Swipe")
public static void swipe (int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int duration) {
    Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(500, 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

External HTTP insecure URLs are now blocked by default. Details are here https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html

Try this config for your mirror if you trust this repo:

```
<mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
      <blocked>false</blocked>
</mirror>
```